# Adding borders to triangles and quadrilaterals (OpenGL GLFW)

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013, geometry, glfw

I have some code for an isosphere that I have in a function that is being called in the main while loop of my code. Everything is working fine except I would like to be able to apply borders around all the individual shapes on the sphere. I will be simplifying this code down eventually, but this is just a test file. Is there anything that I need to add before the while loop to enable borders or something like that?

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
float res = 15, rad = .5;

void display(){

//Create top and bottom cap of isosphere
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);

for (float a = 0; a <= 360; a += res){
    glVertex3f(0, 0, rad);
    glVertex3f(
        rad * (sin((res)* (PI / 180))) * (cos((a)* (PI / 180))),
        rad * (sin((res)* (PI / 180))) * (sin((a)* (PI / 180))),
        rad * (cos((res)* (PI / 180)))
        );
    glVertex3f(
        rad * (sin((res)* (PI / 180))) * (cos((a + res)* (PI / 180))),
        rad * (sin((res)* (PI / 180))) * (sin((a + res)* (PI / 180))),
        rad * (cos((res)* (PI / 180)))
        );

    glVertex3f(0, 0, -rad);
    glVertex3f(
        -rad * (sin((res)* (PI / 180))) * (cos((a)* (PI / 180))),
        -rad * (sin((res)* (PI / 180))) * (sin((a)* (PI / 180))),
        -rad * (cos((res)* (PI / 180)))
        );
    glVertex3f(
        -rad * (sin((res)* (PI / 180))) * (cos((a + res)* (PI / 180))),
        -rad * (sin((res)* (PI / 180))) * (sin((a + res)* (PI / 180))),
        -rad * (cos((res)* (PI / 180)))
        );
}

glEnd();

//Create next part of isosphere
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);

for (int a = res; a <= 360; a += res){
    for (int t = 0; t <= 360; t += res){
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(
            rad * (sin((a)* (PI / 180))) * (cos((t)* (PI / 180))),
            rad * (sin((a)* (PI / 180))) * (sin((t)* (PI / 180))),
            rad * (cos((a)* (PI / 180)))
        );
        glVertex3f(
            rad * (sin((a + res)* (PI / 180))) * (cos((t)* (PI / 180))),
            rad * (sin((a + res)* (PI / 180))) * (sin((t)* (PI / 180))),
            rad * (cos((a + res)* (PI / 180)))
        );
        glVertex3f(
            rad * (sin((a + res)* (PI / 180))) * (cos((t + res)* (PI / 180))),
            rad * (sin((a + res)* (PI / 180))) * (sin((t + res)* (PI / 180))),
            rad * (cos((a + res)* (PI / 180)))
        );
        glVertex3f(
            rad * (sin((a)* (PI / 180))) * (cos((t + res)* (PI / 180))),
            rad * (sin((a)* (PI / 180))) * (sin((t + res)* (PI / 180))),
            rad * (cos((a)* (PI / 180)))
        );
    }
}

glEnd();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Render the sphere two times. Once like you just do and a second time with polygon mode set to GL_LINE:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
```

If you were using modern OpenGL with shaders you could do it in a single draw, if you want to try that leave a comment.

EDIT: Because you asked for modern OpenGL:

You are using immediate mode (glBegin/glEnd) which is outdated. You should read up on buffer objects and shaders. Luckily there are plenty of tutorials out there explaning how these work.

A working example of rendering a model including its wireframe is shown here: http://prideout.net/blog/?p=48
Although primarily it is about tesselation you can have a look at the code to see how the rendering is done.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. How would I try it with modern OpenGL? I think that might be something that might be worth doing.